# insert php result into html document without php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, innerhtml

I want to insert some stuff generated by a PHP code into my HTML document, because I can't use innerHTML with .php extension, but I need that for some ajax. I tried jquery .load() and get(), but I can't get that to work, I'm not really a jquery guy:D

```
$.get("diaknev.php", function(data) { 

    $('#sajt').html(data);

});
```

Comment: post the example that you tried...

Comment: Please post the code you use. We cannot imagine the "stuff" you are generating :)

Comment: When you wanna use jQuery, you can have a look on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get + http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post. It loads the given url and if successful, function(data) {..} will be executed.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code as a part of the question. Comments are not being read by everyone. :)

Comment: post it within the question, edit your question and post relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use an absolute path for the URL:**

```
$.get("/absolute/location/of/diaknev.php", function(data) { 
    $('#sajt').html(data);
});
```

Use **WebDeveloper Tools in your browser** *(F12 in IE)* to track the HTTP and see what happens on the wire.

**PS**: *Consider using `$.ajax` directly and set `dataType` to `'text'`.*

Comment: We should you use an absolute path?

Comment: oh my god I feel so stupid... I mistyped the jquery file's src in the script tag, now it works... sorry for bothering you:D

Comment: @Pieter Because you might be loading the `diaknev.php` from anywhere on the site as it's for Ajax requests and the browser cannot find it. **PS**: *Your very question makes me sad.*

Comment: @user2587370 **Still use an absolute path!** Don't let browsers guess.

Comment: alright, thank you:) should I delete my question now? it can't really help anybody I guess:D

Comment: @user2587370 Delete it but **always use absolute paths** :)